# WebView fails to login when app is first launched

Tags: android, webview

Whenever I try to login to a select website when I FIRST launch my app, the login fails and the WebView just goes to about:blank, but if I refresh and try to login again (and any subsequent time) it works without flaw. Does anyone know why this could be happening?
I'm just opening the page in a WebView object, should act like a normal browser.
If I login with the default browser or Dolphin browser it works fine.

I'm thinking it could have something to do with the website itself, when you login it opens a new window, which I am capturing with my WebView object (and it works on subsequent logins) to just open the new window within the current WebView (I don't need, or want to bother with tabs) using shouldOverrideUrlLoading.

I'm just at a loss why it only fails on the first attempt.

Comment: I managed to finally at least get an error out of my code. Now this appears

    `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate a navigation change for frame with URL data:text/html, from frame with URL https://www.thelearningodyssey.com/.`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setHttpAuthUsernamePassword%28java.lang.String

and

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

This may help you.........